# BBEdit - Have the Sidebar closed by default

Tags: text-editor

Currently whenever I open up BBEdit the Sidebar is open by default.
The Sidebar is where it shows a list of files that were already open in BBEdit. I could shut it down by going to: View > Hide Sidebar

How can I make sure the Sidebar never opens up by default?
I even tried doing in: Preferences > Appearance > Sidebar > Automatically show to Never

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Goto Menu View/Hide Sidebar

Goto Menu Window/Save Default Text Window

After that, each new window will use this settings.

Comment: You can go to Settings > Sidebar and set "automatically show side bar" to "never". But this has no effect at all on the side bar, which is still always show. This answer does the trick! (BBEdit 15.0.1, App Store build)

Answer (score 3):

Preferences -> Application -> Uncheck `Open documents into the front window when possible` which will prevent the need for the sidebar in the first place, preventing it from opening automatically when you've set it to hidden.

It opens regardless of preferences when you open a second (or third, act) document into an existing editor window.

Comment: Note, existing windows will still have the sidebar. To remove the sidebar, use View -> Open in Additional Window